# Find a basis of the following:

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis of the following:

{$p(x) : p(x)=0$ or $p(x)$ is a polynomial in x of degree at most 4 with real coefficients, $p(-2)=0$}.

Plz anyone give me the solution. I tried to solve but can't understand what will be the answer and I think {$1$, $x$, $x^2$, $x^3$, $x^4$} is a basis of this, but not sure. That is why I am asking solution.

Comment: Hint: first, your set cannot be a basis. For example, $x$ evaluated at $-2$ is not zero. Second, if a polynomial $p$ satisfies $p(-2) = 0$, what does that tell you about the factorization of $p$?

Comment: The polynomial is of the form $(x-2)(ax^3 + bx^2 + cx +d)$

Comment: @voldemort One of us is confused...evaluating $p(x) = x$ at $x=-2$ gives $-2$, and $x$ is certainly not the zero polynomial.

Comment: @rogerl: sorry- I had misunderstood the question..

Answer (score 3):

We have $p(-2)=0$ so $-2$ is a root of $p$. The polynomials $x+2, (x+2)^2,(x+2)^3,(x+2)^4$ belong to the given subspace and are linearly independent. Since The given subspace is a proper subspace of $\Bbb R_4[x]$ so it's dimension is less or equal $\dim \Bbb R_4[x]-1=4$ hence we conclude that  $( x+2, (x+2)^2,(x+2)^3,(x+2)^4)$  is a basis of the given subspace.